What information does the admissions committee share with potential advisors / PIs? Disciplinary information?
I am currently a RA at my advisor's lab. My advisor is moving to another university and has encouraged me to apply there for a PhD, with the aim of continuing our work. He said he can try to influence the admissions committee, and to put his name down as my advisor of choice on the application, but he can't make any guarantees since he isn't on the committee.
The problem is that I have a disciplinary record at that university from 8 years ago. Basically, I had to take a semester out due to an alcohol/drug related violation. It has been a long time, and I've since completely recovered from it. Thankfully it doesn't affect my GPA since it technically happened between semesters, and it just shows up as a leave of absence on my transcript, so I've been able to get a Masters, industry jobs and this RA position since then.
However I wouldn't be surprised if the admissions committee at that specific university would see my disciplinary record if they were to search me up internally. For this reason I am not too confident about my chances of getting into the program. But I'm okay with getting rejected as there are many other programs. However, what matters more to me is what my advisor would think. I think the world of him, and I see myself being in his orbit in the foreseeable future (even if not at the same university). so I am very worried that the admissions committee will disclose this information to him somehow.
My question is: is this type of disciplinary information kept confidential from potential advisors who are not on the admissions committee? If I get rejected, could they communicate this as the reason to him?

Usually graduate students moving with their advisor are part of the overall hiring deal. It sounds unusual to me that you would need to apply at the new institution. Or are you still an undergraduate?

No one cares several years later if you were caught with booze or pot in your dorm. Your PI probably had booze or pot in their dorm. They might think you were dumb to get caught.

My best guess is that the worst that could happen would be a question during an interview. But I think that is very unlikely as few would think to look at old disciplinary records or give them any weight from long ago.
It might even be improper for this to re-enter the record for graduate admissions if it was previously handled.
People change. Other people mostly recognize that.
I especially can't see it as a reason for summary rejection at any reputable institution. Certain legal issues might be different (murder,...).
But if you don't apply, then you don't get in.

Indeed, currently, in the U.S., graduate advisors do not (officially!?) have access to students' prior records. For that matter, admissions committees would not routinely search backward investigating applicants' past.
